# Standard Thread safe .Net Dictionary

Tags: .net, multithreading, dictionary

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx) points out that mutating access to the .NET `Dictionary<K,V>` type is not thread safe. Is there a standard thread safe version?

*Note:* "No there is not" is a valid answer if it is true. In that cases (and it seem to be) I'll go off and do the lock thing.

---

### Almost Duplicate

[What’s the best way of implementing a thread-safe Dictionary in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157933/whats-the-best-way-of-implementing-a-thread-safe-dictionary-in-net) (Not exact because I want a standard type, not something I implement my self)

Comment: There's definitely no standard-type. The BCL doesn't provide one for you because there's many different ways to implement thread-safety (using ReaderWriterSlim as I suggest, or a simple lock, which may be good enough). I'm still of the opinion this is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. Consider this code, where each method/property was thread safe

```
if (!SFdict.Contains(key))
{
   SFdict[key] = value;
}
```

athough each action could be threadsafe, the block of code has a race condition, b/c there are two method calls and two different critical sections. The only way to do it is by hand

```
lock(lck)
{
   if (!dict.Contains(key))
   {
      dict[key] = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: An AddOrReturnOld method would work for that. Also your example is a good argument for why there should be standard type that gets these things right

Answer (score 2):

While [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(VS.71).aspx) is not generic, it is thread-safe so long as you use it right (one writer, multiple readers, no enumeration).

> **Thread Safety**
>
> To support one or more writers, all
>   operations on the Hashtable must be
>   done through the wrapper returned by
>   the Synchronized method.
>
> Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. Even when a collection is
>   synchronized, other threads could
>   still modify the collection, which
>   causes the enumerator to throw an
>   exception. To guarantee thread safety
>   during enumeration, you can either
>   lock the collection during the entire
>   enumeration or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other
>   threads.

It is different than a `Dictionary<K, V>` though -- it will return `null`, not throw a `KeyNotFoundException` if you try to get a value that doesn't exist (so storing null values can be problematic). It's a very useful collection if you know you'll never have more than one thread trying to add a new key, and can deal with the `null` issue.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.0 now has a [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.100).aspx) class that seems to do what you want. [Also in .NET 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of the duplicate question, you might want to take a look at [this implementation that uses `ReaderWriterSlim`](http://devplanet.com/blogs/brianr/archive/2008/09/26/thread-safe-dictionary-in-net.aspx). `ReaderWriterSlim` ought to infact offer some performance benefits over simple locking (which effectively uses `Monitor`) - definitely take a look.

Comment: @BCS: I thought the answer should be obvious from the duplicate that there is no standard type. This is the best you're going to get.

Comment: I'll take that that answerer to this one is "No" but that the answerer the the almost duplicate is code how can they be actual duplicates?

Comment: @BCS: See my comment on the question. And anyway, you have your answer now.