# How can I make a thread safe dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a dictionary which I want to make it static. For suppose I have a  dictionary which has some data.If I am accessing this dictionary by two processes at the same time then my data mismatches. How can I solve this problem.

for example     In a dictionary I have    key A- values   1 2 3  4 5 
                                          key B- values   6 7 8 9 10

When I am accessing this dictionary by two processes one reads data for A and other reads data for B. Then I have results sets where B contains A values.

Comment: Rather than start an endless stream of "If your program is written in ..." answers, why don't you tell us which programming language you are writing it in?

Comment: ...and remember to say in future questions too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is written in .NET, you can take a look at this related question regarding [the best way of implementing a thread-safe Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157933/whats-the-best-way-of-implementing-a-thread-safe-dictionary-in-net), with links and C# sample code…

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a ConcurrentDictionary, in System.Collections.Concurrent

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your program is written in Java, you need to synchronize any methods that retrieve and set the values.

For example:

```
public synchronized int getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

The 'synchronized' keyword ensures that two processes do not read or set data concurrently.

This is achieved by the JVM acquiring a lock on the object, to only allow one thread to access it at a time. The code is then executed, and once completed the lock is released. If another thread is waiting, this thread can then acquire a lock on the object.